# Hide git changes/history on the left side

Tags: visual-studio

I would really like to turn off seeing git history changes inside my source file.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the menu, go to `Tools > Options`, then look for `Text Editor > General`.
Uncheck the `Track changes` checkbox and click "Ok":

[image]